# Are all sets of zero measure (not necessarily Lebesgue measure) measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that all sets with Lebesgue outer measure equal to zero are measurable.  This is not hard to prove using the definition of a Lebesgue measurable set, E $\subseteq X$, that I was given : $$m^*(A)= m^*(A\cup E) + m^*(A\cup E^C) ,\forall A\subseteq X$$

But what about the case in a general measure space, $(X,\mathfrak{X} ,\mu)$?

Say $\mu (E)= 0$. Does this imply that $E$ is measurable?

All I have about general measurable sets is that they belong to $\mathfrak{X}$, where $\mathfrak{X}$ is a subset of the power set of $X$ that is closed under compliments and unions and contains $X$ and $\emptyset$.  All I have about the measure, $\mu$, is that it maps from $\mathfrak{X}$ to $[0,\infty]$,
$\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and we have disjoint additivity.

Does the very fact that $\mu(E)$ is defined imply that E is measurable?  This would seem, perhaps, obvious but I am not confident with Measure Theory.  I find it best not to make assumptions.

Comment: $\mu$ is only defined on measurable sets. So writing $\mu(E)=0$, implicitly assumes that $E$ is measurable.

Comment: Thank you for verifying that for me.  It is what I assumed but got thrown off by the concept of the Lebesgue outer measure being defined for all sets in $\mathbb{R}$ whether or not they are measurable.

Can I make your comment the official answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\mu$ is a map $\mathfrak X\longrightarrow[0,\infty]$, so the fact that $\mu(E)$ is defined in the first place makes $E$ an element of $\mathfrak X$, so measurable.

If you're asking about outer measures (which measure spaces don't need!), then your question makes more sense and the answer is still yes, sets of measure $0$ are measurable. Let $\mu^\ast:\mathcal P(X)\longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ be an outer measure, $E\subseteq X$ such that $\mu^\ast(E)=0$. $E$ is measurable by definition if for all $A\subseteq X$ we have $\mu^\ast(A)=\mu^\ast(E\cap A)+\mu^\ast(E^c\cap A)$. Since outer measures are $\sigma$-subadditive this is equivalent to $\mu^\ast(A)\geq \mu^\ast(E\cap A)+\mu^\ast(E^c\cap A)$. Because of monotonicity we have $\mu^\ast(E\cap A)\leq\mu^\ast(E)=0$, so $\mu^\ast(E\cap A)=0$. So we only need to show $\mu^\ast(A)\geq \mu^\ast(E^c\cap A)$. But that's just monotonicity of the outer measure.
So $E$ is measurable.

Comment: Just want to check if I understood correctly. Are you saying, by $\sigma$-subadditivity of outer measures, since $A\subset \left(E\cap A\right) \cup \left(E^c \cap A\right) \cup_i \emptyset$, we have $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*\left(E\cap A\right) + \mu^*\left(E^c \cap A\right)+0+\cdots$, and so we only need to prove the $``\geq''$ part?

Comment: @user760 Yes, that's right.